# How to show craueFormFlow buttons at the top of the form

Tags: symfony, craueformflow

I have a multistep form with Craue FormFlow in Symfony 3.4.

It works well but I need to show the buttons (next, back) on the top of the form as well as the bottom (by default they show at the bottom only).

I had a look at the documentation for the bundle and could not find any info. 
Checking the documentation for Symfony I found that I should be able to use

```
{{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
```

but that gives me an error

```
Neither the property "submit" nor one of the methods "submit()", "getsubmit()"/"issubmit()"/"hassubmit()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".
```

I can add HTML at the top of the form like

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary finish">Next</button>
```

but then I would have to check every step in order to show the right buttons.

I am looking for a more elegant solution if it exists.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can include this template in your form at the beginning and the end :

```
{% include '@CraueFormFlow/FormFlow/buttons.html.twig' %}
```

you can as well use custom classes to improve your display

```
{% include '@CraueFormFlow/FormFlow/buttons.html.twig' with {
            craue_formflow_button_class_last: 'btn btn-primary ml-1',
            craue_formflow_button_class_finish: 'btn btn-success ml-1',  
            craue_formflow_button_class_next: 'btn btn-primary ml-1', 
            craue_formflow_button_class_back: 'btn btn-primary ml-1', 
            craue_formflow_button_class_reset: 'btn btn-warning ml-1'
        }
    %}
```